# SoundPool load() takes a lot of time in Nexus 5 but it is faster in old devices.. ¿Why?

Tags: android, soundpool

i have a soundpool that it is loading 36 small mp3 sounds into a soundpool and it is taking to load them 1 minute in nexus 5 with android 5 and it is taking only 5 seconds on nexus 7 2012 with android 5

how it is this possible?

this is the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<AppSharedValues.mSoundIds.length; i++){
                        mPlayersMap.put(AppSharedValues.mSoundIds[i], soundPool.load(context, AppSharedValues.mSoundIds[i], 0));
                        Log.d("XXXX", "successfully loaded sound: "+i);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known android defect (unfortunately). The bug has been reported in Oct 2014 - but they never fixed it. It is highly recommended that you use an AsyncTask to load.

more information:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1812